# Next.js does not send cookies with fetch request even though credentials are included

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I'm working on a Next.js application which was originally a normal react app (created with create-react-app) and I am trying to send cookies with a fetch request to my server. However, the cookies aren't being sent even though I've set credentials: 'include' in my fetch options.

The exact same code is working in the "not" Next js app.

I also included the "use client" option. The files are in the new "app" folder from next version 13.

**UPDATE 1**: Here is some code I used:

```js
async function getToken() {
  const res = await fetch(
    'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/token', {
      credentials: 'include'
    }
  );
  if (!res.ok) {
    return null;
  }
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Component({
  children
}) {

  const tokenData = getToken();
  const token = await tokenData;

  /* some other code */

  return {
    children
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: Based on the input from edgefish and further experimentation, I acknowledge that in versions of Next.js up to 12, methods such as getServerSideProps could be used. However, since the introduction of the "app" folder in Next.js 13, these methods no longer function within the "app" folder itself (refer to [this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#old-methods)). I'm curious to know if there is a way to incorporate cookies into a fetch request in Next.js 13 using a server-side component. While it's possible to retrieve the client-sent cookie using the cookies method (see [this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies)), I'm unsure how to include that cookie in the subsequent fetch request. Note that using credentials: 'include' is ineffective as long as the component is a server component.

Comment: It may be helpful to post the code snippet that's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To include cookies in Next 13 server-side fetch:

1. Read the request cookies with the [cookies](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) function
2. Add `Cookie` header to the server-side fetch request

```js
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(process.env.API_ENDPOINT, {
    headers: { Cookie: cookies().toString() },
  });
  return await response.json();
}
```

Comment: You can avoid doing the `getAll` and mapping it after, just `cookies().toString()` will do the trick.

Comment: On my side, it works but looks like the request is not memoized at all. So if I am calling the same fetch function from different component, it will hit the API multiple times. Using `cookies` opt-out of caching but the fetch should have been memoized from what I read in https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/patterns#fetching-data-where-its-needed It seems pretty awful.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like it works correctly in production (after a `npm run build`) but not with the dev server.

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js 13, for authorization purposes, it's advised to use both `Sessions` and `Cookies`. Relying solely on `Cookies` is insufficient, especially when managing server-side processes.

For instance, consider you're trying to fetch data from a server-side component like this:

```
async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(process.env.API_ENDPOINT, {
    headers: { Cookie: cookies().toString() },
  });
  return await response.json();
}
```

While you can read the `cookies` in the `API_ENDPOINT`, modifying them directly here may not reflect on the client side. As an example, if you're trying to regenerate a token in the `API_ENDPOINT` using:

```
const response = NextResponse.next();
response.cookies.set({
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    name: JWT_NAME,
    value: "New Token",
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 5000,
    path: '/',
});
return response;
```

The changes you make to the `cookies` won't be reflected in the browser, **because the response here is sent back to the server and not directly to the browser.**

In such scenarios, it's beneficial to use sessions in the same manner as libraries like `next-auth` do.

Answer (score -1):

If you wenna send credentials of fetch in `nextjs` project,
You must use Client-side Rendering (CSR)

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
const YourPage = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(`https://.../data`, fetcher);

   return (
     <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
   );

};
```

OR

If you wenna Server-side Rendering (SSR).

You can using the `getServerSideProps` in `nextjs` project, You can like...

```
import type { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  const { cookie } = context.req.headers;

  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`, {
    headers: { Cookie: cookie },
  });

  const data = await res.json();

  // Pass data to the page
  return { props: { data } };
}
```