# Cookies not found in Go web server from Next client

Tags: authentication, go, next.js

I've switch Authentication for my Go web server, passing from Bearer token to cookies. I've made so that when a user login, I set a cookie for the token and refresh token, like that:

```
a.AuthRepo.StoreInCookie(res.Token, "token", c)
a.AuthRepo.StoreInCookie(res.RefreshToken, "refreshToken", c)
```

where StoreInCookie function is:

```
func (a AuthRepository) StoreInCookie(value, cookieName string, c *gin.Context) {
    c.SetCookie(cookieName, value, 0, "/", "", os.Getenv("ENVIRONMENT") == "prod", false)
}
```

And it works fine when from my nextjs app I do login and then fetch the user detail. The user api has a middleware that check wheter the token is present, otherwise return 401. So the middleware start like that:

```
cookie, err := c.Cookie("token")
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    return
}
token, err := utils.ParseJwt(cookie)
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    return
}
```

After the user fetch I reload the page to re-fetch a list (a list of items you can fetch both with or without being authenticated, you see some more info when you are btw), but in that call the cookie is not present and the middleware does not find it, even though the previous call went well and the cookie was present and through the dev tools I can see in the request the token:

[image]

What am I missing?

EDIT: I understand that only from a client side component the cookies are found correctly from the web server. I realy don't understand why tho

Comment: 1. What is c in your code? 2. Why do you have several cookies with the same name in the request?

Comment: c is *gin.Context because I am using gin for the web server. As for the cookies, mine are token and refresh token, then there is next-auth.csrf-token that I don't know what it is honestly

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution thanks to a previous post here on stackoverflow. I need to manually set the cookies in the header if I fetch from a server component. [For more info check the previous resolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76274546/next-js-does-not-send-cookies-with-fetch-request-even-though-credentials-are-inc)